# Combine regions?

Tags: regions

I can do:

```
Region[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]]
```

And I can do:

```
Region[Circle[{1, 0.5`}, 0.5`, {-90 \[Degree], 90 \[Degree]}]]
```

Can I combine those into one region? Something like:

```
Region[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}] ,Circle[{1, 0.5`}, 0.5`, {-90 \[Degree], 90 \[Degree]}]}]
```

Comment: [RegionUnion](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`RegionUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) gives the union of the regions

```
r1 = Region[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]];
r2 = Region[Circle[{1, 1/2}, 1/2, {-π/2, π/2}]];

RegionUnion[r1, r2]
```

[image]

From Mathematica 10 onwards there is a set of function for [Derived Geometric Regions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedRegions.html) providing several ways of deriving new regions from existing ones, including combining them through Boolean operations and transforming them through a mapping.