# How to discretize the boundary of two regions?

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, mesh, discretization, opencascade

### Problem

How to discretize a surface constructed with multiple components?

Unsuccessful attempts include combining the objects `top` and `hull` using the Mathematica commands `Graphics3D`, `Union`, and `RegionUnion`.

### Other posts investigated

[Combine regions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202265/combine-regions)

[Boundary discretize region of ellipsoid returns a three dimensional region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88327/boundary-discretize-region-of-ellipsoid-returns-a-three-dimensional-region)

[How to combine regions of two 3D plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164242/how-to-combine-regions-of-two-3d-plots)

[RegionUnion issues with many Regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65289/regionunion-issues-with-many-regions)

### Example

Combine and mesh the surface defined by these two blocks:
[image]

```
{length, beam, draft} = {50, 3, 4}
pmin={0, 0, 0};
pmax={length, beam, draft};
hull = Cuboid[pmin, pmax];
{topLength, height} = {30, 3};
pmin = {10, 0, draft};
pmax = pmin + {topLength, beam, height};
top = Cuboid[pmin, pmax];
ohp = RegionUnion[top, hull]
```

#### Fails to discretize:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ohp, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 5}]
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion: A non-degenerate region is expected at position 1
```

Comment: `pmin = {10, 0, draft - 10^-9};` make the pmin of the top very slighty stick into the hull and it works. If you want a shaper edge, reduce the MaxCellMeasure to something like 0.25.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an option using [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html).  OpenCascade is an open source 3D CAD package that often does a better job retaining sharp features with boolean operations and seems to be fairly robust.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
{length, beam, draft} = {50, 3, 4};
pmin = {0, 0, 0};
pmax = {length, beam, draft};
hull = Cuboid[pmin, pmax];
{topLength, height} = {30, 3};
pmin = {10, 0, draft};
pmax = pmin + {topLength, beam, height};
top = Cuboid[pmin, pmax];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[hull];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[top];
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[shape1, shape2];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 MeshRegion[
  MeshOrderAlteration[
   ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 5}], 1]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly different approach also using [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html)

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[ohp, "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "OpenCasdade"]
MeshRegion[bmesh]
```

[image]

Note, however, there is a slight difference in the result compared to Tim's answer. In this case the union is created. I.e. no subdivision between the two cuboids. Tim's answer is a more general approach.

Comment: The simplicity of your solution is great. Wish I could split the vote.

Comment: @dantopa, no worries ;-)